# Sum in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, sum

Why can't I create a sum of total words in this script?  I get the result something like:

```
 120+130
```

but it isn't 250 (as I expected)!   Is there any reason?

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ -z "$count" ] ;
do
    echo -e "request :: please enter file name "
    echo -e "\n\tfile one : \c"
    read count

    itself=counter.sh

    countWords=`wc -w $count |cut -d ' ' -f 1`
    countLines=`wc -l $count |cut -d ' ' -f 1`
    countWords_=`wc -w $itself |cut -d ' ' -f 1`

    echo "Number of lines: " $countLines
    echo "Number of words: " $countWords
    echo "Number of words -script: " $countWords_

    echo "Number of words -total " $countWords+$countWords_  

done

if [ ! -e $count ] ; then
    echo -e "error :: file one $count doesn't exist. can't proceed."
    read empty
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: don't use `<br>`, use the "code sample (ctrl-K)" button.

Answer (score 6):

> echo "Number of words -total "
>   $countWords+$countWords_

You want this:

```
echo "Number of words -total $((countWords + countWords_))"
```

#### Edit

Here are some optimizations to your script.

1. The `while` loop seems pointless
   since `count` is going to get set for
   sure inside making this a
   1-iteration while loop.
2. Your `if` check on existence of the
   file should happen before you ever
   use that file.
3. You don't need to hardcode the name of your script to the variable `itself`, you can use `$0` for that
4. Since you are using `bash` I took the liberty to remove the need for `cut` by using process substitution.

Here is the revised script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "request :: please enter file name "
echo -e "\n\tfile one : \c"
read count

if [ ! -e "$count" ] ; then
    echo "error :: file one $count doesn't exist. can't proceed."
    exit 1
fi

itself="$0"

read countWords _ < <(wc -w $count)
read countLines _ < <(wc -l $count)
read countWords_ _ < <(wc -w $itself)

echo "Number of lines: '$countLines'"
echo "Number of words: '$countWords'"
echo "Number of words -script: '$countWords_'"

echo "Number of words -total $((countWords + countWords_))"
```

Comment: `countWords=$(wc -w < "$count")` will get the count without the file name. Or you could use one call to `wc` instead of two: `read countLines countWords <<< $(wc -lw < "$count")`. `$count` could be null if the user presses enter. This will cause the `while` loop to continue looping until the user inputs something.

Answer (score 1):

One way to go about this is:

```
echo `expr $countWords + $countWords_`
```

Comment: `expr` has been deprecated, use `$(( ))` instead

Comment: @SiegeX, `$(( ))` is bash-syntax, don't break posix bourne shell.

Comment: `$(( ... ))` is [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04) shell; it is also Korn shell (and Bash); it is not Bourne shell.

Comment: @Jonathan thanks for doing my dirty work. This convo seems eerily familiar =)

Comment: @J-16 even if `$(( ))` weren't POSIX syntax, the `#!/bin/bash` at the top of his script would make this a pretty moot point

Comment: @SiegeX: Yup - some moderately familiar territory.  I would hate to think I can't learn... :D